# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'slim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, slim

I am trying to run a training command and getting the following error.

Command:-

```
python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=10000
```

Error:-

```
2022-03-24 23:29:43.298657: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-03-24 23:29:43.298983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\ANPR_Detection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\anprsys\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection import inputs
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\anprsys\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\anprsys\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\anprsys\lib\site-packages\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 28, in <module>
    slim_example_decoder = tf.compat.v1.estimator.slim.tfexample_decoder
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 59, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, item)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\module_wrapper.py", line 232, in _getattr
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'slim'
```

I have already installed slim using `pip install slim` as well as `pip install tf-slim`.

Answer (score 0):

## From tensorflow/models/research/

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

Comment: can you please give more details!! plaese. I guess i have the same issue where I'm getting this error `attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'slim'`. i tried to do export but its not recognizable in my cmd. Also, what do you mean by "From tensorflow/models/research/".