# TF model training command outputs AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run this training command on my system's command prompt:

```
>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config
```

However, I get this attribute error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\module_wrapper.py", line 232, in _getattr
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'slim'
```

I saw this same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607450/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-estimator-python-estimator-api-v1-estimator/71635600#71635600) from @Daremitsu but I could not understand the solution given

bert-tensorflow                 1.0.1
tensorflow                      2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator            2.11.0
tensorflow-intel                2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.29.0
tensorflow-object-detection-api 0.1.1
Python version                  3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tensorflow-slim?

https://pypi.org/project/tf-slim/

if you have tensorflow-slim then check PATH environment variable in Windows

Comment: I tried this and I also tried downgrading TF and still no success.

Comment: @FadyHanna did my suggestion not help, normally it should

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must copy files from several folders to the object detection folder. As I remember it was like that:

folder: `legacy` copy all files to folder: `object detection`

folder: `research/slim` copy whole folder to folder: `object detection`

folder: `/slim/nets` copy whole `nets` to  folder: `object detection`

Tell me if it helps